# Android L Change Theme Colors Error

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I've been following the new steps for Android L here: http://developer.android.com/preview/material/theme.html
I've have been trying to change the colors of the status bar but it doesn't work.

My styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
<!-- Main theme colors -->
<!--   your apps branding color (for the app bar) -->
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<!--   darker variant of colorPrimary (for status bar, contextual app bars) -->
<!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

My colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="primary">#03a9f4</color>
<color name="primary_dark">#0091ea</color>
<color name="accent">#e1f5fe</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Are you running Android L?

Comment: Yes I'm Running Android L on Android Studio 0.8.0 @RossC

Comment: Is this style taken into use within AndroidManifest.xml? Quickly put your files into test project and, well, seems to work ok here.

Comment: <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: Is that what your looking for? I'm pretty sure it's referencing the right thing. @harism

Comment: Could my Emulator settings be the culprit. @harism

Comment: Yes, that's what I was wondering about. Seems ok to me. Unfortunately I really have no idea what happens at your end - I had these style changes work on both emulator and N5.

Comment: Here are my settings: Device: Nexus 5, Target: Android L(Preview) - API Level L, CPU/ABI: IntelAtom (x86), Skin: No Skin, Use Host GPU: YES @harism

Comment: Any advice for what to do? @harism

Comment: Any help with my problem @RossC

Comment: Could This Be of any use?(my build log): emulator: Failed to open the hax module

HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode @harism

Comment: try to use android:statusBarColor

Comment: Likely the theme is not getting picked up at all. Are you seeing the light Material theme in your app? Try switching to Theme.Material. Is it now the dark Material theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. And I fix this by change sdk to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="L" android:targetSdkVersion="L" />
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: But this was before the official launch of the sdk now as of oct 2014 this does not work :(

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by changing the style name in styles.xml and in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to elaborate upon @Allavaz's answer, but his solution worked for me.
I changed the generated theme name in both styles.xml and AndroidManifest.xml from `AppTheme` to a different name.

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

as of oct 2014, It will not be visible in the layout preview but works when viewed inside on the emulator.